# Como enviar request body a través de http en angular

Tags: angular, http

desde el backend se creo un endpoint tipo put para actualizar estados este recibe status de tipo boolean, como puedo hacer para enviar un request body a través de http soy novato en angular y no se como realizarlo

comparto mi service

```
  onChangeStatusOrder = (OrderId, status) => {
    return this.http
      .get<any>(environment.host + 'admin/updateOrderStatus/' + OrderId,{
        headers: this.AuthService.userHeadersJSON(),
      })
      .pipe(map(({ order }: any) => order))
      .toPromise();
  };
}
```

y este es mi ts donde el onchange:

```
  onChange(orderId, element) {
    let status = false;
    if(element.value == "paid") {
      status = true;
    }
    else if(element.value == "toPay") {
      status = false;
    }
    console.log(orderId);
    this.OrdenesService.onChangeStatusOrder(orderId, status).then(() => {

    });
  }
}
```

imagen de la respuesta del endpoint

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si dices que el endpoint es del tipo PUT, solo tienes que usar el método put del httpClient.

```
this.http.put<T>(url, body, options):Observable<T>
```

En tu caso, si lo he entendido bien, quedaría la petición de la siguiente manera.

```
this.http.put(
  environment.host + 'admin/updateOrderStatus/' + OrderId,
  { status },
  { headers: this.AuthService.userHeadersJSON() }
)...
```

Lo que también veo que estas intentando extraer de la respuesta un `order`, pero en la respuesta que pones de Postman, sólo tienes las propiedades `success` y `message`, asi que ese `orders` que estás intentando extraer, será siempre `undefined`.

slds

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta me has salvado la vida llevo con ese problema varios días, la solución funciono perfectamente

Answer (score 0):

> Veo que usas promesas de esa forma no usas las utilidades de Angular ademas de errores que muy bien te marcaron  tener en cuenta que  En Angular Para
> comunicaciones Asincronicas consumiendo un servicio REST  se usan
> Observables toda operacion asincronica en Angular retorna una
> instancia observable debemos subscribirnos a ella para recibir  los
> datos o errores  servicio HttpClient te devuelve directamente el body
> de la respuesta, parseado como JSON.  podemos consumir al observable directamente
> desde la vista con pipes  o directamente en el codigo o en el servicio algunos metodos de HttpClient el cual es un
> cliente con los metodos REST

algunos metodos de HttpClient el cual es un cliente con los metodos REST habituales fijate tipo Observables

**get(url: string, options: {...}): Observable
put(url: string, body: any|null, options: {...}): Observable**

```js
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
// importando y declarando el servicio HttpClient
 constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}
 /*   httpClient dispone de metodos por ejemplo get solicita y retorna a un  objeto oservable JSON desde la API
 el cual lo consumimos mediante el metodo subscribe al hacerlo permitimos que se lance
 admite tres callbacks susbcribe(data, err, end) EL METODO SUBSCRIBE ES IMPRESCINDIBLE No se ejecuta ninguna request hasta que no se llama al método subscribe()
 y se cancela al completar la peticion 
 uso de Observables obtenemos la clase para observar la respuesta http siempre */Observable<MyClass>
 import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
 // por ejemlo 
 public order$!: Observable<Order> ;
 this.order$ = this.httpClient.get<Order>(url)
 En el templete podemos subscribimos tambien por supuesto en el codigo 
 <h3> Order </h3>
<pre>{{ order$ | async | json }}</pre
```

> Entre componentes de Angular usamos para notificaciones de cambios
> BehaviorSubject brindando Observables para subscribirnos a los cambios

```js
interface notificacion {
success:boolean,
message:string
}
private notificaciones!:notificacion[]

private notificaciones$ =new BehaviorSubject<notificacion[]>(this.notificaciones);
public getNotificaciones$=>this.notificaciones$.asObservables();
public enviarNotificacion=(notificacion:notificacion)=>{
this.notificaciones.push(notificacion);
this.notificaciones$.next(this.notificaciones);
};
```

```js
tenes un ejemplo sencillo en https://docs.angular.lat/tutorial/toh-
servicio
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
 private heroesUrl = 'api/heroes';  // URL to web api

  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
  };
/** PUT: update the hero on the server */
  updateHero(hero: Hero): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.put(this.heroesUrl, hero, this.httpOptions).pipe(
      tap(_ => this.log(`updated hero id=${hero.id}`)),
      catchError(this.handleError<any>('updateHero'))
    );
  }
  fijate que debe subscribirse
  servicio detalles
    @Input() hero: Hero;
   save(): void {
    this.heroService.updateHero(this.hero)
      .subscribe(() => this.goBack());
  }
  otros ejemplos en https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-http
  Fijate como usa la subscripcion 
  this.http.put("/courses/-KgVwECOnlc-LHb_B0cQ.json",
    {
        "courseListIcon": ".../main-page-logo-small-hat.png",
        "description": "Angular Tutorial For Beginners TEST",
        "iconUrl": ".../angular2-for-beginners.jpg",
        "longDescription": "...",
        "url": "new-value-for-url"
    },
    {headers})
    .subscribe(
        val => {
            console.log("PUT call successful value returned in body", 
                        val);
        },
        response => {
            console.log("PUT call in error", response);
        },
        () => {
            console.log("The PUT observable is now completed.");
        }
    );
}
```